# Creating a JSON Header on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, json, header

I am converting a script from PHP to ASP.net C#. In PHP, i could use something like:

header('Content-type: text/json');

header('Content-type: application/json');

How can I tell my aspx page to declare in the header that it is printing a JSON file?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

or more generally

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/json");
Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Error "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."  Anyway to get around that without actually enabling this mode?

Answer (score 7):

Additional info about JerSchneid's answer

If you got an error message like this:

> This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

You can use this way:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "text/json");
```